# Please assist with the nutty error

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, github

[image: babluboy/nutty]

Please assist with this error I am getting when I am trying to update my ports in Nutty.

Comment: @florian While embedding an image to the post, please make it clickable (see my edit).

Comment: nutty is an Ubuntu package that can be installed from the Ubuntu Software app in 19.10, but because of the overlapping windows in the screenshot it's impossible to understand this question. Half of a screenshot does not provide sufficient information to answer this question. For starters where did you get the nutty app and how did you install it?